# Moving data retrieving code (websockets) into AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I wrote the following basic AngularJS application. All it does so far is setting up a websocket end asking for some data from it.

This implementation works. What I want to do next is put this code inside of it's on service. Thinking about it I wondered how I will be able to retrieve the data. As long as the websocket code is in the controller I can just update the "entries" array in the onmessage method.

How do I get the data from the service. How to I "attach" my entries array to the service and get it updated by the service?

```
    var mbclient = angular.module('mbclient', ['ngRoute']);

    mbclient.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'homeController'
        });
    });

    mbclient.controller('homeController', ['$log', '$scope', function ($log, $scope) {

    var self = this;
    this.dateFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy';

    this.entries = [];

    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://christians-MBP.fritz.box:8888");

    websocket.onopen = function () {
        $log.info("Socket has been opened");

        var message = JSON.stringify(self.entries);
        websocket.send(message);
    };

    websocket.onclose = function () {
        $log.info("Socket has been closed");
    };

    websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        $log.debug("A message has been received");

        self.entries = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $scope.$digest();
    };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create service with websocket methods and with data field. You can share data between controller and service using references.

```
mbclient.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'homeController'
        });
    });

mbclient.service('webSocketService', ['$log',function($log){

this.entries = []; 

//WebSockets here for example

 websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        angular.extend(this.entries, JSON.parse(event.data));  
    };

}]);

    mbclient.controller('homeController', ['$log', '$scope', 'webSocketService', function ($log, $scope,webSocketService) {

    var self = this;
    this.dateFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy';

    this.entries = webSocketService.entries;

   }
```

You can't assign new array to field with data in service because you lose a reference. You must operate on this field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. It is of course the magic of two way binding ;)

Using your code I get the follwing Error: __Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined__

I guess my JSON is broken?! Here is how it looks: **[{"date":"2015-02-26T18:50:17.254Z","purpose":"Weekly grocery shopping","amount":64,"$$hashKey":"003"}]**

Comment: Altering it to **angular.extend(self.entries, JSON.parse(event.data));** doesn't throw an error anymore. But the view is not getting updated.

Comment: Try to change angular.extend to foreach and push.